# how to transform word problem to an equation ?? is there any trick for this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A team f eleven spies were assigned consecutive whole numbers divisible by eleven as their identity code . For telephonic contact they have to use contact code that equals the product of the middle of the identity code and sum of all identity code of the eleven spies . if last of the identity is 209 then the contact code is ________ .

I am totally blank in this question .

What i Have done is :

no. Spies =11,

S= 11s1+ 12s2+13s3+14s4+......21s11 ..

now i am Confusing what to do  ...

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but if you're doing this for precalc I might suggest that this is a guess-and-check problem. When I looked at this I thought perhaps it could be solved using some deep result of number theory or ring theory but I doubt that's the idea here. Just start at 2, count up, and crack the spies' code that way.

Comment: Hint: this is a very easy question

Comment: i didn't understand

Comment: @rAm As I understand you are multiplying two things together. One is the sum of the identity codes, and one is the middle digit of the contact code. One is a calculation, the other you know. Or am I reading the question wrongly?

Comment: what does mean by middle digit of the code ?? is this mean "1" if I am taking 110 as identity code or its mean 154

Answer (score 2):

You were given that $s_{11} = 209$.  Since the identity codes consist of consecutive multiples of $11$,

$$s_1 = s_{11} - 10 \cdot 11 = 209 - 110 = 99$$

giving the sequence of identity codes $\{99, 110, 121, 132, 143, 154, 165, 176, 187, 198, 209\}$.  Try to complete the problem from there.

Answer (score -1):

Its a old question  i was just solved it for my exams and i came up with the solution. Its a bit tricky question

Spies = **11**

**{S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10,S11}**

and their codes will be
**{99,110,121,132,143,154,165,176,187,198,209}**

Sum of Spies codes = **1694**

Product of the middle of the codes = **1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*0 = 0**

So the contact code will be **0 + 1694 = 1694**